# CMake can't find Boost::thread on Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build windows package of my Qt project.
The following is part of my `CMakeList.txt` file.

```sh
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_DEBUG ON)
set (BOOST_ROOT "C:\\Dev\\boost\\boost_1_78_0")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.70 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)
target_link_libraries(myAppName Boost::thread)
```

The output after I enter `cmake ..` in the `myAppName\build` is

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1658 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1659 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1660 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1661 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1662 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1695 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1696 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1697 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1698 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1699 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1771 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/include;C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1772 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_75_0;boost_1_75_0;boost/boost-1_75_0;boost/boost_1_75_0;boost-1_75;boost_1_75;boost/boost-1_75;boost/boost_1_75;boost-1_74_0;boost_1_74_0;boost/boost-1_74_0;boost/boost_1_74_0;boost-1_74;boost_1_74;boost/boost-1_74;boost/boost_1_74;boost-1_73_0;boost_1_73_0;boost/boost-1_73_0;boost/boost_1_73_0;boost-1_73;boost_1_73;boost/boost-1_73;boost/boost_1_73;boost-1_72_0;boost_1_72_0;boost/boost-1_72_0;boost/boost_1_72_0;boost-1_72;boost_1_72;boost/boost-1_72;boost/boost_1_72;boost-1_71_0;boost_1_71_0;boost/boost-1_71_0;boost/boost_1_71_0;boost-1_71;boost_1_71;boost/boost-1_71;boost/boost_1_71;boost-1_70_0;boost_1_70_0;boost/boost-1_70_0;boost/boost_1_70_0;boost-1_70;boost_1_70;boost/boost-1_70;boost/boost_1_70"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1787 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1827 ] Boost_VERSION = "107800"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1828 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.78.0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1829 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107800"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1830 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1831 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "78"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1832 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1833 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1857 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1858 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-gcc11" (guessed)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1894 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1972 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1976 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1977 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2037 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2038 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- Found Boost: C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0 (found suitable version "1.78.0", minimum required is "1.70")
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1658 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1659 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1660 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1661 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1662 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1694 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1695 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1696 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1697 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1698 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1699 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1787 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1827 ] Boost_VERSION = "107800"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1828 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.78.0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1829 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107800"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1830 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1831 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "78"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1832 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1833 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1857 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1858 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-gcc11" (guessed)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1894 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1972 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1976 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1977 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2037 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2038 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Dev\boost\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1354 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1476 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2223 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc11-mt-1_78;boost_thread-gcc11-mt;boost_thread-gcc11-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_78;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2278 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc11-mt-d-1_78;boost_thread-gcc11-mt-d;boost_thread-gcc11-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-1_78;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2223 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-1_78;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt;boost_chrono-mt-1_78;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2278 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-d-1_78;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-d;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt-d-1_78;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2223 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-1_78;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt;boost_date_time-mt-1_78;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2278 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-d-1_78;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-d;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d-1_78;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2223 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-1_78;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt;boost_atomic-mt-1_78;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2278 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-d-1_78;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-d;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt-d-1_78;boost_atomic-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: thread) (found version "1.78.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.20.0/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2344 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I've tried precompiled version and gcc11 locally compiled version, same output.

I'm using gcc-11 now.

Also tried 1.74.0, similar results except the `New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported targets` warnings.

It seems that cmake didn't find `thread` which is the important package my project used.

It costs me a lot of time to deal with this.

Hoping that someone helps me solving this problem.

Comment: So is there any of the libraries printed after `Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE` in <BOOST_ROOT>\lib ?

Comment: The module version of `find_package` seems to be used here. Try the config version: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread CONFIG)`, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#full-signature (you may need to remove the cache and start the configuration from scratch though). Furthermore double-check, if `C:/Dev/boost/boost_1_78_0/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.78.0` exists and contains cmake script files. Also not sure if cmake properly deals with backslashes in paths; if nothing else works, try replacing the backslashes with slashes in `BOOST_ROOT`...

Comment: I found that ... all boost packages are said to be NOTFOUND
Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND

Comment: @fabian
After adding CONFIG, it shows that
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Boost" with any of
  the following names:

    BoostConfig.cmake
    boost-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Boost" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Boost_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Boost"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Dev/swiftray/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Comment: @fabian
In my `C:\Dev\boost_1_78_0\stage\lib\cmake\boost_thread-1.78.0`
There are `boost_thread-config.cmake` and `boost_thread-config-version.cmake`

Comment: @chehrlic Thank you for reply, I think I don't know which folder should be the `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` I set BOOST INCLUDEDIR to be `set (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:\\Dev\\boost_1_78_0\\boost")` now. The folder contains the `*.hpp` files (sure `thread.hpp`), but still get the same result..